# Return function is not working in my code causing an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm solving a recursion problem in JavaScript. However, when the first if-statement is true, the return-statement is not exiting the script, which results in an infinite loop.

```
function steps(n, row = 0, col = 0, stair = '') {
  if (row === n) {
    return;
  } 

  if (col >= n ) {
    console.log(stair);
    steps(n, row + 1);
  } 

  if (col <= row) {
    stair += '#';
  } else {
    stair += ' ';
  }
  
  steps(n, row, col +1, stair)
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is that you are not returning after your first recursive call, so it will always also execute the second, and that one is not increasing `row`, so it's an infinite loop.

This works:

```js
function steps(n, row = 0, col = 0, stair = '') {
  if (row === n) {
    return;
  } 

  if (col >= n ) {
    console.log(stair);
    steps(n, row + 1);

  } else {
    if (col <= row) {
      stair += '#';
    } else {
      stair += ' ';
    }
  
    steps(n, row, col +1, stair)
  }
}

// try it:
steps(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Christian for pointing out that I'm missing a return. This is my working code now:

```
function steps(n, row = 0, col = 0, stair = '') {

  if (row === n) {
    return 0;
  } 

  if (col >= n ) {
    console.log(stair);
    steps(n, row + 1);
    return;
  } 
  
  if (col <= row) {
    stair += '#';
  } else {
    stair += ' ';
  }
  
  steps(n, row, col +1, stair)
}
```